# How to retrieve data sent in Http Post request using Restlet apis for JavaEE?

Tags: android, rest, jakarta-ee, restlet

Here is my restlet client code on android :

```
    public void sendDataToServer(final JsonObject jsonObject) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String jsonObjectString = jsonObject.toString();
            StringEntity entity = null;
            try {
                entity = new StringEntity(jsonObjectString);
                entity.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://192.168.0.101:8080/RestletDemo/register");
            try {
                Representation representation = clientResource.post(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
//                  representation.getJsonObject();
                Response response = clientResource.getResponse();
                String jsonResponse = response.getEntity().getText();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }).start();


}
```

This code is on the server-side :

```
    @Post("json")
public String registerNumber(JsonRepresentation entity) {

    String serverResponse = "Number Registered";
    try {
//          JsonRepresentation respresentation = new JsonRepresentation();
        String response = this.getRequest().getEntity().getText();
        System.out.println(response);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        serverResponse = gson.toJson(serverResponse);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serverResponse;
}
```

**Current scenario :** I'm able to send post request to the server. Moreover, I'm also able to recieve response. But, I want to retrieve the data sent from the android device(client), in the POST request, on the server. How do I overcome this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue. Here is the server code in order to retrieve POST data, sent from the client, on the server side.

```
    @Post("json")
public Representation registerNumber(Representation entity) {

System.out.println("JsonRepresentation : " + entity);
String postContent;
try {
postContent = entity.getText();
System.out.println("POST Content : " + postContent);
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;

}
```

You can test this code using curl from the terminal:

`curl -i -X POST <your_url> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key" : "value"}'`